# Is fuzzy mathematics useful in pure mathematics ?

Tags: applied-mathematics

Fuzzy sets and logic seem to be mostly used for applying to real-world situations, control-theory, game-theory, economics, statistics, data management, artificial intelligence, automated reasoning etc

Are there any proofs of theorems in pure mathematics of a non-fuzzy nature that make use of fuzzy concepts ?

Fuzzy set theory may be defined axiomatically and therefore be "pure" however here are some quotes from the Fuzzy logic article at Scholarpedia which highlight the applied nature:
"Humans have a remarkable capability to reason and make decisions in an environment of uncertainty, imprecision, incompleteness of information, and partiality of knowledge, truth and class membership. The principal objective of fuzzy logic is formalization/mechanization of this capability."

"During much of its early history, fuzzy logic has been an object of skepticism and derision, in part because fuzzy is a word which is usually used in a pejorative sense. Today, fuzzy logic has an extensive literature and a wide variety of applications ranging from consumer products and fuzzy control to medical diagnostic systems and fraud detection"

If you're thinking that the idea of fuzzy proofs of nonfuzzy theorems is strange, then I would say that it doesn't, on the face of it, seem to me to be any less strange than proofs by the probabilistic method.

Comment: This question has already attracted two votes to close: it is somewhat offensive to people working in "fuzzy mathematics" (of which I don't know anybody), and also, it is very vague. You should rephrase your question (use the *edit* button). Try also to be explicit about the following: what would you like to *learn* from the answer?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: In light of votes to reopen: meta thread now opened http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/907/ for discussion of whether this question should stay closed or be re-opened

Comment: I believe I mildly support the reopening of the question.  Some complained about the last sentence (containing the word "madder").  I found this to be an argumentative rather than contentful question, so I have deleted this sentence.

Comment: It seemed to me that the "madder", if argumentative, might actually have been leaning toward the idea that fuzzy logic is no less "mad" than probabilistic proofs (which have a respectable pedigree after all), i.e., the OP might be sympathetic to there being some merit in fuzzy logic. (This is not to say that the sentiment couldn't have been formulated better, though.) 


Comment: @Todd: I think I agree with you, but it is not a useful way of framing the question.  (After all, there is nothing "mad" about probabilistic proofs...)

Comment: I was astonished at the way way people negatively reacted to this question. I am glad that the question has been reopened. I meant no disparagement to either fuzzy logic or probabilistic proofs. Quite the opposite. The two paragraphs of quotes are from the Scholarpedia article which is curated by the founder of the subject, so I don't understand the request in the meta thread to delete them.

Comment: The final sentence which got edited out and the two quotes were a response to Zev asking me to clarify what I meant by saying Fuzzy is not pure (i.e. applied) and to André saying the question as originally asked was offensive. I'll re-add the final sentence but reworded to hopefully avoid misinterpretation.

Comment: Even after I had expanded the original question André's comment was upvoted which suggests that people still thought it was offensive. I don't see how it is offensive to call something applied.

Comment: @unknown: relax. Don't worry about one comment upvote. If people are at all offended, they will surely let you know. (FWIW, I didn't take what you had written earlier as disparagement.) 

Comment: @unknown: Pete's second comment above is spot-on, I was pretty sure that you probably didn't mean anything negative by it, but I just felt it wasn't the best way of phrasing it. Also, I would highlight that "Are there any proofs of theorems in pure mathematics of a non-fuzzy nature that make use of fuzzy concepts?" is a much more *precise* and *neutral* question than "Is fuzzy math useful in pure math?" - that's why people were criticizing your question as it was initially phrased. Now it is a fine question, and I'm quite interested to see further answers.

Answer (score 7):

Fuzzy measure theory has applications in pure measure theory. The Choquet capacity theorem is a standard tool for showing the universal measurability of analytic sets. The   [theory of capacities](http://aif.cedram.org/item?id=AIF_1954__5__131_0) (or fuzzy measures) is fairly well developed and strongly related to "normal" analysis.

The theory of capacities was not created in the context of fuzzy mathematics, but M. Sugeno developed a form of fuzzy integration in his PhD thesis that shares many formal similarities with the Choquet integral and some work on the Sugeno integral carried over to the Choquet integral.

A rather extensive introduction to these topics is given in the book [Generalized Measure Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441945768) by Wang and Klir.